# Can't append to SVG, even after using namespace

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to append a `circle` to an `svg` element using JavaScript. I when I created the circle, I found out you should use `createElementNS` rather then `createElement`. I did this, and the circle does appear in the HTML, but it still doesn't appear in the page. Here's my code:

```
let ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
let circle = document.createElementNS(ns, 'circle');

circle.setAttributeNS(ns, 'cx', 100);
circle.setAttributeNS(ns, 'cy', 100);
circle.setAttributeNS(ns, 'r', 10);
circle.style.fill = 'red';

svg.appendChild(circle);
```

The output is:

```
<svg><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" style="fill: red;"></circle></svg>
```

But the view is empty. See a Codepen [here.](http://codepen.io/AskYous/pen/qNGEYP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the circle element using the `createElementNS` you don't need the `setAttributeNS`, you should use the `setAttribute` function:

```js
var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var circle = document.createElementNS(ns, 'circle');

circle.setAttribute('cx', 100);
circle.setAttribute('cy', 100);
circle.setAttribute('r', 10);
circle.style.fill = 'red';

svg.appendChild(circle);
```

```css
svg{ width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```